# Regular Expression in oracle 11g how to retrieve data from a column

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have the following data stored in the database column `xyz`:

```
a=222223333;b=433333657675457;c=77777;
a=52424252424242;d=5353535353;b=7373737373;
```

There is no requirement that `b` value should always be there but if `b` value is present I have to retrieve the value following `b=`.

I want to retrieve the value of `b` using regular expressions in Oracle and I am unable to do it.

Can anyone please help me find a solution for this?

Comment: Is there anything that you have tried /(re)searched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using Oracle built-in function [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_substr.php) which returns a substring using regular expressions. According to the example you posted, the following should work.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(xyz, 'b=\d+;') FROM your_table
```

Comment: It doesnt work if the key is, say, "ab" when you are looking for just "b"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_substr`:

```
select substr(regexp_substr(';' || xyz, ';b=\d+'), 4) from your_table;
```

Concatenation with `;` is to distinguish between key-value pair with key say 'ab' and 'b'.

Answer (score 1):

**Use a Subexpression to Select a Substring of Your REGEXP_SUBSTR Matching Pattern**

My match pattern, `'b=(\d+);'`, includes the parenthesis which mark this subexpression which is the last parameter of `REGEXP_SUBSTR`.

If you look at the [12c documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions164.htm#SQLRF06303), you will see that the third example uses a subexpression.

The escaped d just is a regular expression shorthand to indicate that we are looking for digits and the plus symbol is a quantifier indicating 1 or more digits.

```
SCOTT@db>WITH smple AS (
  2      SELECT
  3          'a=52424252424242;d=5353535353;b=7373737373;' dta
  4      FROM
  5          dual
  6  ) SELECT
  7      dta,
  8      regexp_substr(a.dta,'b=(\d+);',1,1,NULL,1) subexp
  9    FROM
 10      smple a;
DTA                                           subexp
---------------------------------------------------------
a=52424252424242;d=5353535353;b=7373737373;   7373737373
```

Comment: Yes,this is failing when there is no b.Please also provide me solution when there is no b.Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

[image]above solution is working in all the cases even if b contains alphanumeric

Comment: This will fail if there is no `b` value. Also please post actual code, not screenshots.